# stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString not working

Tags: cocoa, macos, webkit

This expression doesn't seem to work. It's with a Mac application, not an iPhone app.

```
[[mainWebView mainFrame] stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"document.getElementById('username').value='%@';document.getElementById('password').value='%@';", [ebuddyidField value], [passwordField value]]];
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to send your `stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:` message [to the WebView](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/WebKit/Classes/WebView_Class/Reference/Reference.html%23//apple_ref/occ/instm/WebView/stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString%3a), not to its main frame.

Also, assuming that `ebuddyidField` and `passwordField` are NSTextFields (the latter possibly an NSSecureTextField), they do not respond to a `value` message. The closest message they do respond to is `objectValue`, though you more probably want `stringValue`.

The compiler should have given you warnings for all three problems. Go to your Build Results window and fix every warning. Then [turn some more on](http://boredzo.org/blog/archives/2009-11-07/warnings) and fix those, too. Your application will be much more stable, more robust, and less leaky for it.

Comment: Thanks for the stringValue part, I always forget that. But it doesn't give me any warnings anymore and still it isn't working...

Comment: @icant: Then you need to edit your question both to show your revised code and to be more specific about how it “isn't working”.

Answer (score 0):

That's because `WebFrame` doesn't respond to `-stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:`. That's a method of `UIWebView` on iOS, and has nothing to do with WebKit on Mac OS X.

Try `[[webView windowScriptObject] evaluateWebScript:...]` instead. The result of that method, however, is an `id`, and its type may or may not be `NSString`.

See the `WebScriptObject` class documentation for more info on JavaScript interaction in WebKit on Mac OS X.

**Edit:** Actually, going back and looking at the `WebView` docs, I see it does indeed have a `-stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:` method. So try sending that to the web view rather than the web frame.)

Comment: It says 'No -evaluateWebScript: method found'. This is my code:  [[mainWebView windowScriptObject] evaluateWebScript:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"document.getElementById('username').value='%@';document.getElementById('password').value='%@';", [ebuddyidField value], [passwordField value]]];

Comment: Did you `#import <WebKit/WebKit.h>`?

Comment: Yes, I did import it in the header file.

Comment: In any case, @Peter has the right answer-- send `-stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:` to the `WebView` rather than the `WebFrame`. That should cover it.